# LSP server example

Tags: ocaml

I have a project in which I need to write an LSP server in OCaml for a developing language.
So I did a lot of research on this but I'm having a bit of a hard time getting through it.

The Microsoft tutorial https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification speaks sometimes on the server side, sometimes on the client side, sometimes JSON RPC through which requests and notifications must pass between the client and the server, and all of that mixed up, plus TypeScript and not OCaml, what I want to use as a language confuses me a bit, I feel like I don't understand anything.

So I turned to code. I saw a lot of code like the one from https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/src/lsp, the one from https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-lsp but I don't understand really the code, there are a lot of files with a lot of lines, I don't know what does what.
Can you show me an example of how to initiate connection with the first initiate request, send notification in OCaml. I will use Emacs as client but I know how to do that when the server is ready. I think a little example will help me do the rest.

Comment: don't worry, this is complex; you need to split your problems into smaller parts. First of all, in your case Emacs is the client, the server is written in OCaml, and probably your developing language is interpreted in OCaml. Between the client and the server, the data is exchanged using a format known as JSON-RPC, with a header (like in HTTP, in fact you could use an HTTP server library). The JSON messages must match the defined API (requests, responses) as described in the protocol.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, and sorry for the delay, i was not able to work for two days. I've found how to connect the server to the client emacs, and now, I'm trying to use the https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-lsp server to connect it to emacs and see how it's work.